# MySQL - Query For Rows With Updates Based On Another Table

Tags: mysql, one-to-many

I have a table called `listings` with many fields like `id`, `name`, `address` etc.

I have another table called `listing_updates` with many of the same fields like `id`, `name`, `address` and also a status field with values like `NEW`, `CANCELLED`, `CLOSED`, etc.

A listing has many listing updates (one-to-many)

I want a query that does the following:

**SELECT all of the listings where the latest update for that listing is in the `NEW` status**

The "latest update" in the case is defined by the row with the greatest `id` (auto-incrementing) with the correct listing association.

Hopefully, any answer given will be able to expand to if we add more statuses in future.

Comment: I have an answer with many fields also, but it's a bit vague, so I'm going to go with this instead https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following [Query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40c06f/8/0) selects all `listings` for which the latest update has `status` "NEW":

```
SELECT
  l.*, 
  u.status 
FROM 
  listings AS l
  INNER JOIN listing_updates AS u ON (l.id = u.listing_id)
WHERE 
  u.id = (
    SELECT MAX(id) 
    FROM listing_updates AS u2 
    WHERE u2.listing_id = l.id
  )
  AND u.status = 'NEW'
```

`SELECT`, `FROM` and `JOIN` should be pretty self explanatory if you know basic SQL. In the `WHERE` clause the `id` of the update record is restricted to the last (`MAX`) id of all updates for the current listing using a subquery. Last only results with `status` "NEW" are selected. This discards all listings, which have a last update with a different status.

Comment: This sounds very promising. I'll give this a go later on and then accept if it all works out